# Как сделать запрос отображения данных mysql за 24 часа?

Tags: mysql

Вот мой запрос через PDO на отображения данных за 24 часа:

```
prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `base` WHERE date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');
```

То есть он отображает все данные за 24 часа постоянно.

Как составить запрос так, чтобы данные после 00:00 считались заново до 00:00 ?

То есть происходил новый отсчет, те данные которые поступили после 00:00 и до 00:00 считались по новой.

Comment: лучше бы вы пример данных привели чего считать, чем так объяснять. чего хотите то, чтобы не за 24 часа было а с нуля часов, или что?

Comment: Да, с нуля часов до нуля следующий и потом по новой вот с нуля до нуля 20 данных поступило , потом новый день и новые данные с нуля опять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вам нужны данные с группировкой по суткам. то так и напишите

```
select `date`, count(*)
from t
group by `date`
order by `date` desc
```

Если у вас поле `date` имеет тип `DATETIME` а не `DATE`, то извлеките из него часть даты без времени c помошью функции `DATE()` и сделайте то же самое. То ест вместо `date` будет `DATE(date)`.

Если вам нужны данные за последние сутки, то опять же сравните дату с текущей без всяких группировок уже

```
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM t
 WHERE `date` = CURRENT_DATE()            #или DATE(`date`) = ..
```

Comment: Второй вариант мне подошел, спасибо .